Questions about Alfred Noyes' Midnight Express #1: Why did Mortimer forget what he read in the battered old book?
I have this(these) question(s) regarding Alfred Noyes' "Midnight Express"
Because I have about ten questions regarding this, I will post each individually.
I don't want to give any exerpt because I think the story itself is so complicated and intricately interconnected that it is best to give the story a quick read. But still, for the sake of some context, here is a relevant part:

The battered old book had the strangest fascination for him though he never quite grasped the thread of the story. It was called The Midnight Express, and there was one illustration, on the fiftieth page, at which he could never bear to look. It frightened him.
Young Mortimer never understood the effect of that picture on him. He was an imaginative, but not a neurotic youngster; and he avoided the fiftieth page as he might have hurried past a dark corner on the stairs when he was six years old, or as the grown man on the lonely road, in The Ancient Mariner, who, having once looked round, walks on, and turns no more his head. There was nothing in the picture – apparently – to account for this haunting dread. Darkness, indeed, was almost its chief characteristic. It showed an empty railway platform – at night – lit by a single dreary lamp: an empty railway platform that suggested a deserted and lonely junction in some remote part of the country. There was only one figure on the platform: the dark figure of a man, standing almost directly under the lamp with his face turned away towards the black mouth of a tunnel which – for some strange reason – plunged the imagination of the child into a pit of horror. The man seemed to be listening. His attitude was tense, expectant, as though he were awaiting some fearful tragedy. There was nothing in the text, so far the child read, and could understand, to account for this waking nightmare. He could neither resist the fascination of the book, nor face that picture in the stillness and loneliness of the night. He pinned it down to the page facing it with two long pins, so that he should not come upon it by accident. Then he determined to read the whole story through. But, always, before he came to page fifty, he fell asleep; and the outlines of what he had read were blurred; and the next night he had to begin again; and again, before he came to the fiftieth page, he fell asleep.

So here's my first doubt:

Why Mortimer could not remember what he read in the red battered old book and he had to start it again the next time he read?

I have read the story so many times but still I can't make the head and tail out of the story. These are the questions lingering in my mind ever since I read the story. I found no satisfactory answers in the internet.
Thanks in advance!

I think you should post them individually, or at least somewhat more thematically; that's recommended practice. Containing multiple questions in one is grounds for closure, even if the individual questions are interesting.

@CDR Ok. But what do you mean by, "somewhat more thematically"?

I mean that if one or two of them are very closely linked (or if one's a follow-up to another, etc.), they could be posted together. But ten individual ones is fine, too.

First, there is a physiological reason why he might have to reread after having fallen asleep. Human short term memory lasts about 15-30 seconds, whereupon it is erased if not transferred to a longer term memory. Unconsciousness interrupts that transferral process and this is why we can never really remember the moment that we fall asleep. Adding the tendency of dreams to bleed into one's memory, I've personally had the experience of having to backspace several pages when I fall asleep reading a book, because I have forgotten the last few pages, and I am unsure of how much of my memories are true.
That said, with a span of 50 pages, and the context of the rest of the story, I think it is likely that this is simply a matter of the book being an inherently eldritch thing, such that Mortimer's brain refuses to hold onto its contents. Eventually, the force attached to the book finally traps him.
If a non-supernatural explanation is preferred, stress and fear impair the formation of long term memory. Mortimer entered each session of reading the book with the dread of reaching that 50th paqe, which would likely put him in a state of further memory impairment, possibly mixed the aforementioned difficulty of understanding where his dreams melded with what he had actually read. Under that interpretation, the end of the story has Mortimer trapped in yet another nightmare, which might end normally, or which he might have passed away during, ensuring that it never truly ends.
